# How can I access context's req in Nuxt3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3, nuxt-content, vuejs3-composition-api

How can I access context's req in Nuxt3?

nuxt2

```
asyncData({req}) {
const body = req.body;
}
```

I used useRequestEvent().req.body and useNuxtApp().event.req.body.
but both is undefined.

nuxt3

```
const event = useRequestEvent()
const body = event.req.body;

const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
const { ssrContext } = nuxtApp;
const body = ssrContext.event.req.body
```

Is there another way to access request body?

Comment: `useRequestEvent()` is only available in pages, components, and plugins

Comment: I used it pages. Is there correct way to get request data like nux2 version?